# Parse Tree for a proper structured sentence using OpenNLP

Tags: nlp, opennlp, parse-tree

I have an NLP task where I need to make sure that a paragraph of multiple sentences include at least one well structured question, I'm using OpenNLP to generate the parse trees in the paragraph. My questions are:

1-Is there a way to get a list of possible parse trees for a properly structured question.

2- How can I compare two parse trees

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well,you yourself have answered the question. You just have to get the dataset containing different types of questions and play with it.

1. Get different types of questions and parse trees corresponding to it. Get all the output parse trees in a format such that you can use it in the next step.
2. When it comes to comparing to parse trees,it's basically comparing text. Which is a quite simple task.

But obviously,doing it like this will take a bit longer time and memory if you directly play with text files. For that,convert and save your parse trees of standard questions in binary and this will take less time and memory when concatenated with the next step.

Hope this helps,All the best!

Comment: I was able to check if a question exists, but not able to check is the sentence has proper grammar.

Comment: I'm trying to use LanguageTool but it is only checking for spelling problems, it is suppose to check for grammar also, but can't figure out how

Comment: by proper grammar, we mean a certain arrangement of POS, for which you can create a binary file containing all formats and check if your data is matching with any of it. doesn't that solve your question?

Comment: Is there a place where I can find a list of correct sentence formats

Comment: collect a set of proper questions, and use POStagger and use that data